# Adding a "View on Site" link to the Django admin list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to add a "View on site" link to my list_display in Django Admin.

This seems like a pretty common use case, is there a shortcut way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

You could write a reusable mixin like this (untested):

```
class ViewOnSiteMixin(object):
    def view_on_site(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(u"<a href='%s'>view on site</a>" % obj.get_absolute_url())
    view_on_site.allow_tags = True
    view_on_site.short_description = u"View on site"
```

Use it like this:

```
class SomeAdmin(ViewOnSiteMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., "view_on_site", ...]
```

(of course needs `get_absolute_url` defined on your model)

Comment: This works perfectly, it only needs to import mark_safe: _from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe_

Answer (score 2):

Using [view_on_site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.view_on_site) will muck up the "View on site" link within the admin view - that link shows up when you set [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) for your model.

Instead you can use just about any other name for that column, just match it with the function name.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class ServisAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (.. ,'view_link')

    def view_link(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(
                obj.get_absolute_url(),
                _("View on site")
            )
        )
    view_link.allow_tags = True
    view_link.short_description = _("View on site")
```